# Graphing in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

How would I draw something like this in Latex? I really have no idea. Help is much appreciated!!
[image: Second order differential equations]

Comment: Welcome between the users of TeX.SE.

Comment: You could use `pgfplots`. Depending on the complexity of the function I would use `pgfplots` in combination with `gnuplot`. You can find a list of pgfplots examples here: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Answer (score 3):

There are already quite a few such plots around, and here is one more.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[semithick,-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[below left]{$y$};
 \draw[semithick,-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0) node[below left]{$t$};
 \draw[red,very thick] (2,1) to[out=40,in=180,looseness=1.6] (3.5,1)
  to[out=00,in=180] (4.2,1.2) node[above,black]{$y=\phi(t)$}
   to[out=00,in=190,looseness=1.7] (5.5,1);
 \draw[dashed] (2,0) node[below]{$t_0$} |- (0,1) node[left]{$y_0$} 
    node[pos=0.5,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt](d){};
 \draw[thick] (d) + (220:1) -- ++ (40:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.85](p);
 \draw[latex-] (p) -- ++ (130:1) node[above] {$\mbox{slope}=y'(t_0)=y_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano Grazie! Fixed.